# Why does cancelBubble work in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am confused I thought that `cancelBubble` is IE-only Boolean property but found it in Chrome.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble supported by all browsers. `The cancelBubble property of the Event interface is a historical alias to Event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1):

From early on, the Chrome folks took the approach of trying to be broadly compatible with existing code, which in some cases meant being compatible with code written using IE-only features. Another example of this is the global `event` variable, an IE-specific variable set to the current event during event callbacks (so callbacks use the global rather than an argument as they do with `addEventListener`). Chrome has supported that since the beginning for IE-specific code that relied on it; Firefox has only recently started supporting the global `event` variable. Supporting `cancelBubble` is in that same category.

They *don't* support every IE-specific thing (for instance, not `attachEvent`), so as to avoid messing with code trying to detect IE event handling and branch. But they support a lot of IE-isms.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.